# string型から文字列へ変換

Tags: python, python3

データが最終的にテキストになっていますが、表記は0xで始まる１６進データでした
その中から、特定の文字列を探し、以降のデータを出力するというものです
「いいね！」という文字列があるとします

抜き出した文字列は「いいね！」なので
`e38184e38184e381adefbc8100000000000000000000000000000000`

これを「いいね！」にデコードしたいのですがわかりませんでした
コード自体がstringとなっているところから、どう加工するか教えていただけないでしょうか

```
come = 'e38184e38184e381adefbc8100000000000000000000000000000000'
come.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
```

これでは元の文字列をただコード変換しているだけのようでダメでした

提示いただいた処理でうまく変換出来ました

Comment: tanalab2 さんが参照している記事に書いてありますが、`bytes.fromhex('e38184e38184e381adefbc8100000000000000000000000000000000').decode('utf-8')` としても良さそうです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>以下はどうでしょうか?

(ただし、"00..."部分はゴミデータと思います。)</del>

<del>import banish   

 # binascii.unhexlify で16進表記の字列をバイナリデータに変換後、utf-8文字列にデコードしています。

  str(binascii.unhexlify('e38184e38184e381adefbc8100000000000000000000000000000000'), 'utf-8')</del>

※追記
metropolis さんが記載の以下が余計なimportもなく一番シンプルだと思います。

```
bytes.fromhex('e38184e38184e381adefbc8100000000000000000000000000000000').decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: ちなみに utf8 hex decoder python でググった結果、検索された  https://qiita.com/masakielastic/items/21ba9f68ef6c4fd7692d をまるままパクっています。